# Writing about sets (especially subsets and supersets) in terms of their elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am currently working through some set-theory-texts, trying to prove different basic theorems. Therefore, i often replace the notation for the set as a whole with the rules that apply to an element of the set. (example: $A\cup B = \{x | x \in A \lor x \in B \} $).

I do the same when the statement involves a subset: $A \subset B = \{x|x\in A \land x\in B \} $.
For the statement to hold true, this rule would indeed have to apply, but of course it doesn't really reflect the statement. $A\subset B$ feels more like it should translate into the implication: $x\in A \implies x\in B$. 
In some cases this might however not be as easy to work with as the above form.

Really even the equal-sign after $A \subset B$ feels misplaced, as the subset-expression doesn't seem to be a set in itself (in contrast to the union of two sets), but rather just information about a set, and can therfore not be equal to $A \subset B = \{x|x\in A \land x\in B \} $.

So i guess my question is: What is the common way to translate the notion of a subset (or superset) into a statement applying to an element x, instead of to the set as a whole.

Comment: $A\subset B \iff (x\in A\implies x\in B)\iff A\cap B=A\iff A\cup B = B$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you sir. These equivalences were indeed one of the first things i needed to prove :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

> $A \subset B \equiv \forall x(x \in A \to x \in B)$

(i) '$\equiv$' expresses the equivalence between the proposition on the left and the one on the right (or you can equally use '$\leftrightarrow$').

(ii) And plainly you need a conditional on the right, not a conjunction  -- $A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if for any $x$, IF $x$ is in $A$ THEN $x$ is in $B$.

Comment: Thank you! I have an intuition about the relationships in set-theory, but clearly lack knowledge of some notation and rules :)